# Generate multiple PDF files in a more efficient way (time consuming) from R

Tags: r, pdf

I'm following this method https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_mail_merge.html to generate multiple PDF files and it works perfectly. But when the volume of PDF is big (hundreds of them) it requires a lot of time.

Is there any other way of doing the same but more efficiently?

Comment: What do you mean by "inefficient"? It might be slow to render many R Markdown files because there is a lot to do in the process (run code chunks, convert to Markdown, convert to Latex, compile latex to PDF). You can think about saving intermediate files which do not change or run on multiple cores.

Comment: Maybe inefficient is not the good word. What I mean is if you need 15 seconds to generate 1 PDF, you will need 4 hours for 700 PDFs. And if the volume of costumers grows, you will end needing more and more hours. So I'm wondering if there's a way to make it faster. I actually don't need to open the PDFs, the PDFs are generated because they will be later attached to a mail send from R massively to all the costumers.